# How to bind multiple mouse buttons to a widget?

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I'm trying to make  the Minesweeper game. For each undifferentiated square I created a button.

```
my_list = [[0 for i in range(9)] for j in range(9)]

all_buttons = []


def creaMatriz():
    for y, row in enumerate(my_list):
        buttons_row = [] 
        for x, element in enumerate(row):
            boton2 = Button(root, text="", width=6, height=3, command=lambda a=x, b=y: onButtonPressed(a, b))
            boton2.grid(row=y, column=x)
            buttons_row.append(boton2)
        all_buttons.append(buttons_row)


def onButtonPressed(x, y):
    all_buttons[y][x]['text'] = str(qwer[x][y]) # Some action!!!
....
```

When i press the left mouse button on a undifferentiated square,  I'm calling the function `onButtonPressed(x, y)`, and a digit or a mine appears on the square.

**How can I call another function when pressing the right mouse button on a undifferentiated square. I want see 'M' on the square.**

full code: http://pastebin.com/cWGS4fBp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing special you need to do, you simply need to bind each mouse button separately rather than using the `command` attribute.

For example, let's create a callback for the left and right mouse buttons:

```
def onLeftClick(x, y):
    print("you clicked on %x,%y" % (x, y))

def onRightClick(x, y):
    print("you clicked on %x,%y" % (x, y))
```

Next, we can bind to each of those functions separately using the `bind` method. Since we're adding custom bindings, we do *not* want to set the `command` attribute of the button.

```
def creaMatriz():
    for y, row in enumerate(my_list):
        buttons_row = [] 
        for x, element in enumerate(row):
            button = Button(root, text="", width=6, height=3)
            ...
            button.bind("<1>", lambda event, x=x, y=y: onLeftClick(x,y))
            button.bind("<3>", lambda event, x=x, y=y: onRightClick(x,y))
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to bind keys you wish in order to get this functionality. Here's a simple concept:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def left(event):
    label.config(text="Left clicked")

def right(event):
    label.config(text="Right clicked")

label = Label(root, text="Nothing")
label.pack()

label.focus_set()
label.bind("<1>", left)
label.bind("<3>", right)
```

Let us know if it is what you're looking for.

Comment: I have 9*9=81 buttons without names. list all_buttons with 81 buttons and they coordinates (x,y). I don't know how to bind keys to the buttons without a names.